# "Sufficient(ly)": quantitative vs qualitative

Tags: determiners, style-manuals

[Garner's reads](https://books.google.es/books?id=FwmQpyibKkAC&lpg=PA17&dq=%22Though%20both%20words%20were%20originally%20used%20in%20reference%20to%20quantity%22&hl=es&pg=PA17#v=onepage&q=%22Though%20both%20words%20were%20originally%20used%20in%20reference%20to%20quantity%22&f=false)

> Though both words were originally used in reference to quantity,
> *adequate* now tends toward the *qualitative* and **sufficient** toward the *quantitative*.

However, [Fowler says](https://books.google.es/books?id=w2NjCgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA215&dq=As%20an%20adjective%20(or%20modifier)%2C%20*enough*%20will%20normally%20serve%2C&hl=es&pg=PA215#v=onepage&q=As%20an%20adjective%20(or%20modifier),%20*enough*%20will%20normally%20serve,&f=false)

> As an adjective (or modifier), *enough* will normally serve, but
> **sufficient** is more idiomatic when a more *qualitative* point is being made

Which is correct?

Comment: Phew. Two heavyweights slugging it out. I'd add a caveat that answers containing mere opinion will be downvoted.

Comment: If either of them coulda defined either _qualitative_ or _quantitative_ with sufficient precision, they wouldna had to resort to hand-waving.

Comment: Why does only one have to be correct? From most quantitative to most qualitative, the order goes "enough" --> "sufficient" --> "adequate". (I'm not saying that that's correct, only that Garner and Fowler aren't inconsistent.)

Comment: @MarcInManhattan Indeed. The question is on a wonky premise, since *adequate* and *enough* are different contexts to think of the usage of *sufficient*. Even if I think both Garner and Fowler overstate the distinctions between *adequate*, *sufficient*, and *enough*, the two usage suggestions are reconcilable.